# Using BeautifulSoup to get text from <pre> element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract the DNA sequence from [this site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MT755607.1?report=fasta) but I can't seem to access the data. My code is shown below. If it's any help, I was also following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/XQgXKtPSzUI) on data scraping and the beginning of my code should seem similar to theirs.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bslol

# URl to web scrape from
page_url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MT755607.1?report=fasta'

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
# as if it were a json data type.
page_soup = bslol(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()
```

To get the text, I first tried using `print(page_soup.select('pre'))`, which returned empty brackets.

Then I tried doing `page_soup.find('div', {'class':'seq gbff'}).text` as well as `page_soup.find('div', {'class':'seq gbff'}).content` but to no avail. I also tried using `.findAll` to see if there was any change, but that brought me nowhere closer to a solution.

If anyone can help me out with this problem, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you analyse the website, website makes an ajax call to load the dna sequence.

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=1877761002&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000')

dna_sequence = res.text.strip()

print(dna_sequence)
```

Output:

```
>MT755607.1 Homo sapiens haplogroup A2-T16189C mitochondrion, complete genome
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTTTGGGGG
GTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTC
CTGCCCCATCCTGTTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTACTAAAGTGTGTTA
ATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAGTAATAACAATTGAATGTCTGCACAGCCGCTTTCCACACAGACATC
ATAACAAAAAATTTCCACCAAACCCCCCCCTCCCCCCGCTTCTGGCCACAGCACTTAAACACATCTCTGC
CAAACCCCAAAAACAAAGAACCCTAACACCAGCCTAACCAGATTTCAAATTTTATCTTTTGGCGGTATGC
ACTTTTAACAGTCACCCCCCAACTAACACATTATTTTCCCCTCCCACTCCCATACTACTAATCTCATCAA
TACAACCCCCGCCCATCCTACCCAGCACACACACCGCTGCTAACCCCATACCCCGAACCAACCAAACCCC
AAAGACACCCCCCACAGTTTATGTAGCTTACCTCCTCAAAGCAATACACTGAAAATGTTTAGACGGGCTC
ACATCACCCCATAAACAAATAGGTTTGGTCCTGGCCTTTCTATTAGCTCTTAGTAAGATTACACATGCAA
GCATCCCCGTTCCAGTGAGTTCACCCTCTAAATCACCACGATCAAAAGGGACAAGCATCAAGCACGCAGC
AATGCAGCTCAAAACGCTTAGCCTAGCCACACCCCCACGGGAAACAGCAGTGATTAACCTTTAGCAATAA
ACGAAAGTTTAACTAAGCTATACTAACCCCAGGGTTGGTCAATTTCGTGCCAGCCACCGCGGTCACACGA
TTAACCCAAGTCAATAGAAGCCGGCGTAAAGAGTGTTTTAGATCACCCCCTCCCCAATAAAGCTAAAACT
CACCTGAGTTGTAAAAAACTCCAGTTGACACAAAATAGACTACGAAAGTGGCTTTAACATATCTGAACAC
ACAATAGCTAAGACCCAAACTGGGATTAGATACCCCACTATGCTTAGCCCTAAACCTCAACAGTTAAATC
AACAAAACTGCTCGCCAGAACACTACGAGCCACAGCTTAAAACTCAAAGGACCTGGCGGTGCTTCATATC
CCTCTAGAGGAGCCTGTTCTGTAATCGATAAACCCCGATCAACCTCACCACCTCTTGCTCAGCCTATATA
CCGCCATCTTCAGCAAACCCTGATGAAGGCTACAAAGTAAGCGCAAGTACCCACGTAAAGACGTTAGGTC
AAGGTGTAGCCCATGAGGTGGCAAGAAATGGGCTACATTTTCTACCCCAGAAAACTACGATAGCCCTTAT
GAAACTTAAGGGTCGAAGGTGGATTTAGCAGTAAACTGAGAGTAGAGTGCTTAGTTGAACAGGGCCCTGA
AGCGCGTACACACCGCCCGTCACCCTCCTCAAGTATACTTCAAAGGACATTTAACTAAAACCCCTACGCA
TTTATATAGAGGAGACAAGTCGTAACATGGTAAGTGTACTGGAAAGTGCACTTGGACGAACCAGAGTGTA
GCTTAACACAAAGCACCCAACTTACACTTAGGAGATTTCAACTTAACTTGACCGCTCTGAGCTAAACCTA
GCCCCAAACCCACTCCACCTTACTACCAGACAACCTTAGCCAAACCATTTACCCAGATAAAGTATAGGCG
ATAGAAATTGAAACCTGGCGCAATAGATATAGTACCGCAAGGGAAAGATGAAAAATTATAACCAAGCATA
ATATAGCAAGGACTAACCCCTATACCTTCTGCATAATGAATTAACTAGAAATAACTTTGCAAGGAGAGCC
AAAGCTAAGACCCCCGAAACCAGACGAGCTACCTAAGAACAGCTAAAAGAGCACACCCGTCTATGTAGCA
AAATAGTGGGAAGATTTATAGGTAGAGGCGACAAACCTACCGAGCCTGGTGATAGCTGGTTGTCCAAGAT
AGAATCTTAGTTCAACTTTAAATTTGCCCACAGAACCCTCTAAATCCCCTTGTAAATTTAACTGTTAGTC
CAAAGAGGAACAGCTCTTTGGACACTAGGAAAAAACCTTGTAGAGAGAGTAAAAAATTTAACACCCATAG
TAGGCCTAAAAGCAGCCACCAATTAAGAAAGCGTTCAAGCTCAACACCCACTACCTAAAAAATCCCAAAC
ATATAACTGAACTCCTCACACCCAATTGGACCAATCTATCACCCTATAGAAGAACTAATGTTAGTATAAG
TAACATGAAAACATTCTCCTCCGCATAAGCCTGCGTCAGATTAAAACACTGAACTGACAATTAACAGCCC
AATATCTACAATCAACCAACAAGTCATTATTACCCTCACTGTCAACCCAACACAGGCATGCTCATAAGGA
AAGGTTAAAAAAAGTAAAAGGAACTCGGCAAATCTTACCCCGCCTGTTTACCAAAAACATCACCTCTAGC
ATCACCAGTATTAGAGGCACCGCCTGCCCAGTGACACATGTTTAACGGCCGCGGTACCCTAACCGTGCAA
AGGTAGCATAATCACTTGTTCCTTAAATAGGGACCTGTATGAATGGCTCCACGAGGGTTCAGCTGTCTCT
TACTTTTAACCAGTGAAATTGACCTGCCCGTGAAGAGGCGGGCATGACACAGCAAGACGAGAAGACCCTA
TGGAGCTTTAATTTATTAATGCAAACAGTACCTAACAAACCCACAGGTCCTAAACTACCAAACCTGCATT
AAAAATTTCGGTTGGGGCGACCTCGGAGCAGAACCCAACCTCCGAGCAGTACATGCTAAGACTTCACCAG
TCAAAGCGAACTACTATACTCAATTGATCCAATAACTTGACCAACGGAACAAGTTACCCTAGGGATAACA
GCGCAATCCTATTCTAGAGTCCATATCAACAATAGGGTTTACGACCTCGATGTTGGATCAGGACATCCCG
ATGGTGCAGCCGCTATTAAAGGTTCGTTTGTTCAACGATTAAAGTCCTACGTGATCTGAGTTCAGACCGG
AGTAATCCAGGTCGGTTTCTATCTACTTCAAATTCCTCCCTGTACGAAAGGACAAGAGAAATAAGGCCTA
CTTCACAAAGCGCCTTCCCCCGTAAATGATATCATCTCAACTTAGTATTATACCCACACCCACCCAAGAA
CAGGGTTTGTTAAGATGGCAGAGCCCGGTAATCGCATAAAACTTAAAACTTTACAGTCAGAGGTTCAATT
CCTCTTCTTAACAACATACCCATGGCCAACCTCCTACTCCTCATTGTACCCATTCTAATCGCAATGGCAT
TCCTAATGCTTACCGAACGAAAAATTCTAGGCTATATACAACTACGCAAAGGCCCCAACGTTGTAGGCCC
CTACGGGCTACTACAACCCTTCGCTGACGCCATAAAACTCTTCACCAAAGAGCCCCTAAAACCCGCCACA
TCTACCATCACCCTCTACATCACCGCCCCGACCTTAGCTCTCACCATCGCTCTTCTACTATGAACCCCCC
TCCCCATACCCAACCCCCTGGTCAACCTCAACCTAGGCCTCCTATTTATTCTAGCCACCTCTAGCCTAGC
CGTTTACTCAATCCTCTGATCAGGGTGAGCATCAAACTCAAACTACGCCCTGATCGGCGCACTGCGAGCA
GTAGCCCAAACAATCTCATATGAAGTCACCCTAGCCATCATTCTACTATCAACATTACTAATAAGTGGCT
CCTTTAACCTCTCCACCCTTATCACAACACAAGAACACCTCTGATTACTCCTGCCATCATGACCCTTGGC
CATAATATGATTTATCTCCACACTAGCAGAGACCAACCGAACCCCCTTCGACCTTGCCGAAGGGGAGTCC
GAACTAGTCTCAGGCTTCAACATCGAATACGCCGCAGGCCCCTTCGCCCTATTCTTCATAGCCGAATACA
CAAACATTATTATAATAAACACCCTCACCACTACAATCTTCCTAGGAACAACATATGACGCACTCTCCCC
TGAACTCTACACAACATATTTTGTCACCAAGACCCTACTTCTAACCTCCCTGTTCTTATGAATTCGAACA
GCATACCCCCGATTCCGCTACGACCAACTCATACACCTCCTATGAAAAAACTTCCTACCACTCACCCTAG
CATTACTTATATGATATGTCTCCATACCCATTACAATCTCCAGCATCCCCCCTCAAACCTAAGAAATATG
TCTGATAAAAGAGTTACTTTGATAGAGTAAATAATAGGAGCTTAAACCCCCTTATTTCTAGGACTATGAG
AATCGAACCCATCCCTGAGAATCCAAAATTCTCCGTGCCACCTATCACACCCCATCCTAAAGTAAGGTCA
GCTAAATAAGCTATCGGGCCCATACCCCGAAAATGTTGGTTATACCCTTCCCGTACTAATTAATCCCCTG
GCCCAACCCGTCATCTACTCTACCATCTTTGCAGGCACACTCATCACAGCGCTAAGCTCGCACTGATTTT
TTACCTGAGTAGGCCTAGAAATAAACATGCTAGCTTTTATTCCAGTTCTAACCAAAAAAATAAACCCTCG
TTCCACAGAAGCTGCCATCAAGTATTTCCTCACGCAAGCAACCGCATCCATAATCCTTCTAATAGCTATC
CTCTTCAACAATATACTCTCCGGACAATGAACCATAACCAATACTACCAATCAATACTCATCATTAATAA
TCATAATGGCTATAGCAATAAAACTAGGAATAGCCCCCTTTCACTTCTGAGTCCCAGAGGTTGCCCAAGG
CACCCCTCTGACATCCGGCCTGCTTCTTCTCACATGACAAAAACTAGCCCCCATCTCAATCATATACCAA
ATCTCTCCCTCACTAAACGTAAGCCTTCTCCTCACTCTCTCAATCTTATCCATCATAGCAGGCAGTTGAG
GTGGATTAAACCAAACCCAGCTACGCAAAATCTTAGCATACTCCTCAATTACCCACATAGGATGAATAAT
AGCAGTTCTACCGTACAACCCTAACATAACCATTCTTAATTTAACTATTTATATTATCCTAACTACTACC
GCATTCCTACTACTCAACTTAAACTCCAGCACCACGACCCTACTACTATCTCGCACCTGAAACAAGCTAA
CATGACTAACACCCTTAATTCCATCCACCCTCCTCTCCCTAGGAGGCCTGCCCCCGCTAACCGGCTTTTT
GCCCAAATGGGCCATTATCGAAGAATTCACAAAAAACAATAGCCTCATCATCCCCACCATCATAGCCACC
ATCACCCTCCTTAACCTCTACTTCTACCTACGCCTAATCTACTCCACCTCAATCACACTACTCCCCATAT
CTAACAACGTAAAAATAAAATGACAGTTTGAACATACAAAACCCACCCCATTCCTCCCCACACTCATCGC
CCTTACCACGCTACTCCTACCTATCTCCCCTTTTATACTAATAATCTTATAGAAATTTAGGTTAAATACA
GACCAAGAGCCTTCAAAGCCCTCAGTAAGTTGCAATACTTAATTTCTGTAACAGCTAAGGACTGCAAAAC
CCCACTCTGCATCAACTGAACGCAAATCAGCCACTTTAATTAAGCTAAGCCCTTACTAGACCAATGGGAC
TTAAACCCACAAACACTTAGTTAACAGCTAAGCACCCTAATCAACTGGCTTCAATCTACTTCTCCCGCCG
CCGGGAAAAAAGGCGGGAGAAGCCCCGGCAGGTTTGAAGCTGCTTCTTCGAATTTGCAATTCAATATGAA
AATCACCTCGGAGCTGGTAAAAAGAGGCCTAACCCCTGTCTTTAGATTTACAGTCCAATGCTTCACTCAG
CCATTTTACCTCACCCCCACTGATGTTCGCCGACCGTTGACTATTCTCTACAAACCACAAAGACATTGGA
ACACTATACCTATTATTCGGCGCATGAGCTGGAGTCCTAGGCACAGCTCTAAGCCTCCTTATTCGAGCCG
AGCTGGGCCAGCCAGGCAACCTTCTAGGTAACGACCACATCTACAACGTTATCGTCACAGCCCATGCATT
TGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATACCCATCATAATCGGAGGCTTTGGCAACTGACTAGTTCCCCTAATA
ATCGGTGCCCCCGATATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCTTACCTCCCTCTCTCC
TACTCCTGCTCGCATCTGCTATAGTGGAGGCCGGGGCAGGAACAGGTTGAACAGTCTACCCTCCCTTAGC
AGGGAACTACTCCCACCCTGGAGCCTCCGTAGACCTAACCATCTTCTCCTTACACCTAGCAGGTGTCTCC
TCTATCTTAGGGGCCATCAATTTCATCACAACAATTATCAATATAAAACCCCCTGCCATAACCCAATACC
AAACGCCCCTCTTCGTCTGATCCGTCCTAATCACAGCAGTCCTACTTCTCCTATCTCTCCCAGTCCTAGC
TGCTGGCATCACTATACTACTAACAGACCGCAACCTCAACACCACCTTCTTCGACCCCGCCGGAGGAGGA
GACCCCATTCTATACCAACACCTATTCTGATTTTTCGGTCACCCTGAAGTTTATATTCTTATCCTACCAG
GCTTCGGAATAATCTCCCATATTGTAACTTACTACTCCGGAAAAAAAGAACCATTTGGATACATAGGTAT
GGTCTGAGCTATGATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCGTGTGAGCACACCATATATTTACAGTAGGA
ATAGACGTAGACACACGAGCATATTTCACCTCCGCTACCATAATCATCGCTATCCCCACCGGCGTCAAAG
TATTTAGCTGACTCGCCACACTCCACGGAAGCAATATGAAATGATCTGCTGCAGTGCTCTGAGCCCTAGG
ATTCATCTTTCTTTTCACCGTAGGTGGCCTGACTGGCATTGTATTAGCAAACTCATCACTAGACATCGTA
CTACACGACACGTACTACGTTGTAGCTCACTTCCACTATGTCCTATCAATAGGAGCTGTATTTGCCATCA
TAGGAGGCTTCATTCACTGATTTCCCCTATTCTCAGGCTACACCCTAGACCAAACCTACGCCAAAATCCA
TTTCACTATCATATTCATCGGCGTAAATCTAACTTTCTTCCCACAACACTTTCTCGGCCTATCCGGAATG
CCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACATGAAACATCCTATCATCTGTAGGCTCATTCA
TTTCTCTAACAGCAGTAATATTAATAATTTTCATGATTTGAGAAGCCTTCGCTTCGAAGCGAAAAGTCCT
AATAGTAGAAGAACCCTCCATAAACCTGGAGTGACTATATGGATGCCCCCCACCCTACCACACATTCGAA
GAACCCGTATACATAAAATCTAGACAAAAAAGGAAGGAATCGAACCCCCCAAAGCTGGTTTCAAGCCAAC
CCCATGGCCTCCATGACTTTTTCAAAAAGGTATTAGAAAAACCATTTCATAACTTTGTCAAAGTTAAATT
ATAGGCTAAATCCTATATATCTTAATGGCACATGCAGCGCAAGTAGGTCTACAAGACGCTACTTCCCCTA
TCATAGAAGAGCTTATCACCTTTCATGATCACGCCCTCATAATCATTTTCCTTATCTGCTTCCTAGTCCT
GTATGCCCTTTTCCTAACACTCACAACAAAACTAACTAATACTAACATCTCAGACGCTCAGGAAATAGAA
ACCGTCTGAACTATCCTGCCCGCCATCATCCTAGTCCTCATCGCCCTCCCATCCCTACGCATCCTTTACA
TAACAGACGAGGTCAACGATCCCTCCCTTACCATCAAATCAATTGGCCACCAATGGTACTGAACCTACGA
GTACACCGACTACGGCGGACTAATCTTCAACTCCTACATACTTCCCCCATTATTCCTAGAACCAGGCGAC
CTGCGACTCCTTGACGTTGACAATCGAGTAGTACTCCCGATTGAAACCCCCATTCGTATAATAATTACAT
CACAAGACGTCTTGCACTCATGAGCTGTCCCCACATTAGGCTTAAAAACAGATGCAATTCCCGGACGTCT
AAACCAAACCACTTTCACCGCTACACGACCGGGGGTATACTACGGTCAATGCTCTGAAATCTGTGGAGCA
AACCACAGTTTCATGCCCATCGTCCTAGAATTAATTCCCCTAAAAATCTTTGAAATAGGGCCCGTATTTA
CCCTATAGCACCCCCTCTACCCCCTCTAGAGCCCACTGTAAAGCTAACTTAGCATTAACCTTTTAAGTTA
AAGATTAAGAGAACCAACACCTCTTTACAGTGAAATGCCCCAACTAAATACTACCGTATGGCCCACCATA
ATTACCCCCATACTCCTTACACTATTCCTCATCACCCAACTAAAAATATTAAACACAAACTACCACCTAC
CTCCCTCACCAAAGCCCATAAAAATAAAAAATTATAACAAACCCTGAGAACCAAAATGAACGAAAATCTG
TTCGCTTCATTCATTGCCCCCACAATCCTAGGCCTACCCGCCGCAGTACTGATCATTCTATTTCCCCCTC
TATTGATCCCCACCTCCAAATATCTCATCAACAACCGACTAATCACCACCCAACAATGACTAATCAAACT
AACCTCAAAACAAATGATAACCATACACAACACTAAAGGACGAACCTGATCTCTTATACTAGTATCCTTA
ATCATTTTTATTGCCACAACTAACCTCCTCGGACTCCTGCCTTACTCATTTACACCAACCACCCAACTAT
CTATAAACCTAGCCATGGCCATCCCCTTATGAGCGGGCGCAGTGATTATAGGCTTTCGCTCTAAGATTAA
AAATGCCCTAGCCCACTTCTTACCACAAGGCACACCTACACCCCTTATCCCCATACTAGTTATTATCGAA
ACCATCAGCCTACTCATTCAACCAATAGCCCTGGCCGTACGCCTAACCGCTAACATTACTGCAGGCCACC
TACTCATGCACCTAATTGGAAGCGCCACCCTAGCAATATCAACCATTAACCTTCCCTCTACACTTATCAT
CTTCACAATTCTAATTCTACTGACTATCCTAGAAATCGCTGTCGCCTTAATCCAAGCCTACGTTTTCACA
CTTCTAGTAAGCCTCTACCTGCACGACAACACATAATGACCCACCAATCACATGCCTATCATATAGTAAA
ACCCAGCCCATGACCCCTAACAGGGGCCCTCTCAGCCCTCCTAATGACCTCCGGCCTAGCCATGTGATTT
CACTTCCACTCCATAACGCTCCTCATACTAGGCCTACTAACCAACACACTAACCATATACCAATGATGGC
GCGATGTAACACGAGAAAGCACATACCAAGGCCACCACACACCACCTGTCCAAAAAGGCCTTCGATACGG
GATAATCCTATTTATTACCTCAGAAGTTTTTTTCTTCGCAGGATTTTTCTGAGCCTTTTACCACTCCAGC
CTAGCCCCTACCCCCCAATTAGGAGGGCACTGGCCCCCAACAGGCATCACCCCGCTAAATCCCCTAGAAG
TCCCACTCCTAAACACATCCGTATTACTCGCATCAGGAGTATCAATCACCTGAGCTCACCATAGTCTAAT
AGAAAACAACCGAAACCAAATAATTCAAGCACTGCTTATTACAATTTTACTGGGTCTCTATTTTACCCTC
CTACAAGCCTCAGAGTACTTCGAGTCTCCCTTCACCATTTCCGACGGCATCTACGGCTCAACATTTTTTG
TAGCCACAGGCTTCCACGGACTTCACGTCATTATTGGCTCAACTTTCCTCACTATCTGCTTCATCCGCCA
ACTAATATTTCACTTTACATCCAAACATCACTTTGGCTTCGAAGCCGCCGCCTGATACTGGCATTTTGTA
GATGTGGTTTGACTATTTCTGTATGTCTCCATCTATTGATGAGGGTCTTACTCTTTTAGTATAAATAGTA
CCGTTAACTTCCAATTAACTAGTTTTGACAACATTCAAAAAAGAGTAATAAACTTCGCCTTAATTTTAAT
AATCAACACCCTCCTAGCCTTACTACTAATAATTATTACATTTTGACTACCACAACTCAACGGCTACATA
GAAAAATCCACCCCTTACGAGTGCGGCTTCGACCCTATATCCCCCGCCCGCGTCCCTTTCTCCATAAAAT
TCTTCTTAGTAGCTATTACCTTCTTATTATTTGATCTAGAAATTGCCCTCCTTTTACCCCTACCATGAGC
CCTACAAACAACTAACCTGCCACTAATAGTTATGTCATCCCTCTTATTAATCATCATCCTAGCCCTAAGT
CTGGCCTATGAGTGACTACAAAAAGGATTAGACTGAACCGAATTGGTATATAGTTTAAACAAAACGAATG
ATTTCGACTCATTAAATTATGATAATCATATTTACCAAATGCCCCTCATTTACATAAATATTATACTAGC
ATTTACCATCTCACTTCTAGGAATACTAGTATATCGCTCACACCTCATATCCTCCCTACTATGCCTAGAA
GGAATAATACTATCGCTGTTCATTATAGCTACTCTCATAACCCTCAACACCCACTCCCTCTTAGCCAATA
TTGTGCCTATTGCCATACTAGTCTTTGCCGCCTGCGAAGCAGCGGTGGGCCTAGCCCTACTAGTCTCAAT
CTCCAACACATATGGCCTAGACTACGTACATAACCTAAACCTACTCCAATGCTAAAACTAATCGTCCCAA
CAATTATATTACTACCACTGACATGACTTTCCAAAAAACACATAATTTGAATCAACACAACCACCCACAG
CCTAATTATTAGCATCATCCCTCTACTATTTTTTAACCAAATCAACAACAACCTATTTAGCTGTTCCCCA
ACCTTTTCCTCCGACCCCCTAACAACCCCCCTCCTAATACTAACTACCTGACTCCTACCCCTCACAATCA
TGGCAAGCCAACGCCACTTATCCAGTGAACCACTATCACGAAAAAAACTCTACCTCTCTATACTAATCTC
CCTACAAATCTCCTTAATTATAACATTCACAGCCACAGAACTAATCATATTTTATATCTTCTTCGAAACC
ACACTTATCCCCACCTTGGCTATCATCACCCGATGAGGCAACCAGCCAGAACGCCTGAACGCAGGCACAT
ACTTCCTATTCTACACCCTAGTAGGCTCCCTTCCCCTACTCATCGCACTAATTTACACTCACAACACCCT
AGGCTCACTAAACATTCTACTACTCACTCTCACTGCCCAAGAACTATCAAACTCCTGAGCCAACAACTTA
ATATGACTAGCTTACACAATAGCTTTTATAGTAAAGATACCTCTTTACGGACTCCACTTATGACTCCCTA
AAGCCCATGTCGAAGCCCCCATCGCTGGGTCAATAGTACTTGCCGCAGTACTCTTAAAACTAGGCGGCTA
TGGTATAATACGCCTCACACTCATTCTCAACCCCCTGACAAAACACATAGCCTACCCCTTCCTTGTACTA
TCCCTATGAGGCATAATTATAACAAGCTCCATCTGCCTACGACAAACAGACCTAAAATCGCTCATTGCAT
ACTCTTCAATCAGCCACATAGCCCTCGTAGTAACAGCCATTCTCATCCAAACCCCCTGAAGCTTCACCGG
CGCAGTCATTCTCATAATCGCCCACGGACTTACATCCTCATTACTATTCTGCCTAGCAAACTCAAACTAC
GAACGCACTCACAGTCGCATCATAATCCTCTCTCAAGGACTTCAAACTCTACTCCCACTAATAGCTTTTT
GATGACTTCTAGCAAGCCTCGCTAACCTCGCCTTACCCCCCACTATTAACCTACTGGGAGAACTCTCTGT
GCTAGTAACCACGTTCTCCTGATCAAATATCACTCTCCTACTTACAGGACTCAACATACTAGTCACAGCC
CTATACTCCCTCTACATATTTACCACAACACAATGAGGCTCACTCACCCACCACATTAACAACATAAAAC
CCTCATTCACACGAGAAAACACCCTCATGTTCATACACCTATCCCCCATTCTCCTCCTATCCCTCAACCC
CGACATCATTACCGGGTTTTCCTCTTGTAAATATAGTTTAACCAAAACATCAGATTGTGAATCTGACAAC
AGAGGCTTACGACCCCTTATTTACCGAGAAAGCTCACAAGAACTGCTAACTCATGCCCCCATGTCTAACA
ACATGGCTTTCTCAACTTTTAAAGGATAACAGCTATCCATTGGTCTTAGGCCCCAAAAATTTTGGTGCAA
CTCCAAATAAAAGTAATAACCATGCACACTACTATAACCACCCTAACCCTGACTTCCCTAATTCCCCCCA
TCCTTACCACCCTCGTTAACCCTAACAAAAAAAACTCATACCCCCATTATGTAAAATCCATTGTCGCATC
CACCTTTATTATCAGTCTCTTCCCCACAACAATATTCATGTGCCTAGACCAAGAAGTTATTATCTCGAAC
TGACACTGAGCCACAACCCAAACAACCCAGCTCTCCCTAAGCTTCAAACTAGACTACTTCTCCATAATAT
TCATCCCTGTAGCATTGTTCGTTACATGGTCCATCATAGAATTCTCACTGTGATATATAAACTCAGACCC
AAACATTAATCAGTTCTTCAAATATCTACTCATTTTCCTAATTACCATACTAATCTTAGTTACCGCTAAC
AACCTATTCCAACTGTTCATCGGCTGAGAGGGCGTAGGAATTATATCCTTCTTGCTCATCAGTTGATGAT
ACGCCCGAGCAGATGCCAACACAGCAGCCATTCAAGCAATCCTATACAACCGTATCGGCGATATCGGTTT
CATCCTCGCCTTAGCATGATTTATCCTACACTCCAACTCATGAGACCCACAACAAATAGCCCTTCTAAAC
GCTAATCCAAGCCTCACCCCACTACTAGGCCTCCTCCTAGCAGCAGCAGGCAAATCAGCCCAATTAGGTC
TCCACCCCTGACTCCCCTCAGCCATAGAAGGCCCCACCCCAGTCTCAGCCCTACTCCACTCAAGCACTAT
AGTTGTAGCAGGAATCTTCTTACTCATCCGCTTCCACCCCCTAGCAGAAAATAGCCCACTAATCCAAACT
CTAACACTATGCTTAGGCGCTATCACCACTCTGTTCGCAGCAGTCTGCGCCCTTACACAAAATGACATCA
AAAAAATCGTAGCCTTCTCCACTTCAAGTCAACTAGGACTCATAATAGTTACAATCGGCATCAACCAACC
ACACCTAGCATTCCTGCACATCTGTACCCACGCCTTCTTCAAAGCCATACTATTTATGTGCTCCGGGTCC
ATCATCCACAACCTTAACAATGAACAAGATATTCGAAAAATAGGAGGACTACTCAAAACCATACCTCTCA
CTTCAACCTCCCTCACCATTGGCAGCCTAGCATTAGCAGGAATACCTTTCCTCACAGGTTTCTACTCCAA
AGACCACATCATCGAAACCGCAAACATATCATACACAAACGCCTGAGCCCTATCTATTACTCTCATCGCT
ACCTCCCTGACAAGCGCCTATAGCACTCGAATAATTCTTCTCACCCTAACAGGTCAACCTCGCTTCCCCA
CCCTTACTAACATTAACGAAAATAACCCCACCCTACTAAACCCCATTAAACGCCTGGCAGCCGGAAGCCT
ATTCGCAGGATTTCTCATTACTAACAACATTTCCCCCGCATCCCCCTTCCAAACAACAATCCCCCTCTAC
CTAAAACTCACAGCCCTCGCTGTCACTTTCCTAGGACTTCTAACAGCCCTAGACCTCAACTACCTAACCA
ACAAACTTAAAATAAAATCCCCACTATGCACATTTTATTTCTCCAACATACTCGGATTCTACCCTAGCAT
CACACACCGCACAATCCCCTATCTAGGCCTTCTTACGAGCCAAAACCTGCCCCTACTCCTCCTAGACCTA
ACCTGACTAGAAAAGCTATTACCTAAAACAATTTCACAGCACCAAATCTCCACCTCCATCATCACCTCAA
CCCAAAAAGGCATAATTAAACTTTACTTCCTCTCTTTCTTCTTCCCACTCATCCTAACCCTACTCCTAAT
CACATAACCTATTCCCCCGAGCAATCTCAATTACAATATATACACCAACAAACAATGTTCAACCAGTAAC
TACTACTAATCAACGCCCATAATCATACAAAGCCCCCGCACCAATAGGATCCTCCCGAATCAACCCTGAC
CCCTCTCCTTCATAAATTATTCAGCTTCCTACACTATTAAAGTTTACCACAACCACCACCCCATCATACT
CTTTCACCCACAGCACCAATCCTACCTCCATCGCTAACCCCACTAAAACACTCACCAAGACCTCAACCCC
TGACCCCCATGCCTCAGGATACTCCTCAATAGCCATCGCTGTAGTATATCCAAAGACAACCATCATTCCC
CCTAAATAAATTAAAAAAACTATTAAACCCATATAACCTCCCCCAAAATTCAGAATAATAACACACCCGA
CCACACCGCTAACAATCAATACTAAACCCCCATAAATAGGAGAAGGCTTAGAAGAAAACCCCACAAACCC
CATTACTAAACCCACACTCAACAGAAACAAAGCATACATCATTATTCTCGCACGGACTACAACCACGACC
AATGATATGAAAAACCATCGTTGTATTTCAACTACAAGAACACCAATGACCCCAATACGCAAAATTAACC
CCCTAATAAAATTAATTAACCACTCATTCATCGACCTCCCCACCCCATCCAACATCTCCGCATGATGAAA
CTTCGGCTCACTCCTTGGCGCCTGCCTGATCCTCCAAATCACCACAGGACTATTCCTAGCCATGCACTAC
TCACCAGACGCCTCAACCGCCTTTTCATCAATCGCCCACATCACTCGAGACGTAAATTATGGCTGAATCA
TCCGCTACCTTCACGCCAATGGCGCCTCAATATTCTTTATCTGCCTCTTCCTACACATCGGGCGAGGCCT
ATATTACGGATCATTTCTCTACTCAGAAACCTGAAACATCGGCATTATCCTCCTGCTTGCAACTATAGCA
ACAGCCTTCATAGGCTATGTCCTCCCGTGAGGCCAAATATCATTCTGAGGGGCCACAGTAATTACAAACT
TACTATCCGCCATCCCATACATTGGGACAGACCTAGTTCAATGAATCTGAGGAGGCTACTCAGTAGACAG
TCCCACCCTCACACGATTCTTTACCTTTCACTTCATCTTGCCCTTCATTATTGCAGCCCTAGCAGCACTC
CACCTCCTATTCTTGCACGAAACGGGATCAAACAACCCCCTAGGAATCACCTCCCATTCCGATAAAATCA
CCTTCCACCCTTACTACACAATCAAAGACGCCCTCGGCTTACTTCTCTTCCTTCTCTCCTTAATGACATT
AACACTATTCTCACCAGACCTCCTAGGCGACCCAGACAATTATACCCTAGCCAACCCCTTAAACACCCCT
CCCCACATCAAGCCCGAATGATATTTCCTATTCGCCTACACAATTCTCCGATCCGTCCCTAACAAACTAG
GAGGCGTCCTTGCCCTATTACTATCCATCCTCATCCTAGCAATAATCCCCATCCTCCATATATCCAAACA
ACAAAGCATAATATTTCGCCCACTAAGCCAATCACTTTATTGACTCCTAGCCGCAGACCTCCTCATTCTA
ACCTGAATCGGAGGACAACCAGTAAGCTACCCTTTTACCATCATTGGACAAGTAGCATCCGTACTATACT
TCACAACAATCCTAATCCTAATACCAACTATCTCCCTAATTGAAAACAAAATACTCAAATGGGCCTGTCC
TTGTAGTATAAACTAATACACCAGTCTTGTAAACCGGAGATGAAAACCTTTTTCCAAGGACAAATCAGAG
AAAAAGTCTTTAACTCCACCATTAGCACCCAAAGCTAAGATTCTAATTTAAACTATTCTCTGTTCTTTCA
TGGGGAAGCAGATTTGGGTACCACCCAAGTATTGACTCACCCATCAACAACCGCTATGTACTTCGTACAT
TACTGCCAGTCACCATGAATATTGTACGGTACCATAAATACTTGACCACCTGTAGTACATAAAAACCCAA
TCCACATCAAAACCCCCCCCCCATGCTTACAAGCAAGTACAGCAATCAACCTTCAACTATCACACATCAA
CTGCAACTCCAAGGCCACCCCTCACCCACTAGGATACCAACAAACCTATCCACCCTTGACAGTACATAGT
ACATAAAACCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTACAGTCAAATCCCTTCTCGCCCCCATGGATGACCCCCCT
CAGATAGGGGTCCCTTGACCACCATCCTCCGTGAAATCAATATCCCGCACAAGAGTGCTACTCTCCTCGC
TCCGGGCCCATAACACTTGGGGGTAGCTAAAGTGAACTGTATCCGACATCTGGTTCCTACTTCAGGGCCA
TAAAGCCTAAATAGCCCACACGTTCCCCTTAAATAAGACATCACGATG
```

Comment: How did you know that the page loads data from this specific page?  'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=1877761002&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000' Is there any way to know, like from google network inspector or sort of? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

actually the site uses JavaScript to load that `<pre></pre>` code block. `urllib.request` can't load content which requires JavaScript loading. Use `selenium` to load the page in a browser (Edge, Firefox or Chrome) and then you can load the page into the bs4 parser to parse the HTML content. You can also use Selenium only to scrape data from a website without using bs4 parser.

Head over to the official site - https://www.selenium.dev/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create lines and extract info from lines.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ""
page = requests.get(url)
if (page.status_code == 200):
    html_text = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
data= html_text.find_all('pre')[0].get_text()
lines  = [x.split(';') for x in data.split('\n') if x != ' \r']
print(lines)
```